# The values on x-axis are descending values on grouped bar chart using d3.js

Tags: html, d3.js, data-visualization

I have transformed the vertical grouped bar chart from horizontal grouped bar chart. I have taken the code from the site  https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051. The problem is when I have transformed horizontal to vertical axis the values on x-axis are not ascending but they are descending i.e., the values are 10M, 8M, 6M, 4M etc....I am not sure where I have made a mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 140},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 900 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0],.1);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("top").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("height", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("width", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; });

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
  x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Population");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "state")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + x0(d.State) + ")"; });

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("height", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      //.attr("x", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 10)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 14)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You y-scale which is used on your x-axis is defined as:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0] , 0.1);
```

This runs it in reverse and should be:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, height] , 0.1);
```